# Почему при вызове `max(int, long long)` аргумент типа int не расширяется до long long?

Tags: c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему этот код:

```
int x = 1;
long long y = 1;
cout << max(x, y) << endl;
```

[не скомпилируется](https://ideone.com/EMurHM) с ошибкой

> no matching function for call to 'max(int&, long long int&)'

Есть ведь функция `max(long long, long long)`, что мешает аргументу типа `int` автоматически преобразоваться в `long long`?

(чтобы скомпилировалось надо явно преобразовать аргумент типа `int` к `long long`, это я знаю)

Comment: А `#include <algorithm>` кто за вас будет делать? Пушкин?

Comment: @AnT `<iostream>`, кажется, включает этот `std::max`

Comment: В вашем случае - да. Но это не более чем "паразитное" включение, случайность.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Никакой "функции `max(long long, long long)`" нет.

Речь идет о стандартном `std::max`. И надо иметь в виду, что `std::max` - это шаблон. Тип аргументов `std::max` заранее не задан - он является шаблонным параметром. Шаблон этот лишь определен так, что тип аргументов функции должен быть одинаковым.

Из вашего вызова `max(x, y)` компилятор не может угадать, какой именно тип аргумента `std::max` вы хотели получить. Может быть вы хотели использовать `long long` в качестве общего типа. А может быть вы хотели использовать `int` в качестве общего типа.

Выполнить дедукцию шаблонного аргумента в такой ситуации компилятор не может и компиляция заканчивается с ошибкой. Т.е. проблема заключается именно в невозможности дедукции шаблонного аргумента для `std::max`.

В данном случае вы можете, например, "подавить" дедукцию шаблонного аргумента, т.е. указать тип шаблонного аргумента явно вручную

```
max<long long>(x, y)
```

и тогда действительно аргумент типа `int` будет неявно преобразован к типу `long long`, как вы и хотели.

Comment: @AnT, ещё можно отметить, что выводятся аргументы-ссылки, поскольку там 2 переменные.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, но аргументы там - всегда ссылки. Однако, так как ссылки там *константные* (точнее, *на константу*), ссылочность типов аргументов тут принципиальной роли не играет.

Comment: @user268670: в общем случае, при желании можно автоматически общий тип получить, используя `std:common_type` и/или decltype См. [C++11 way to write template for picking bigger integer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12575898/4279)

Comment: @jfs, прикольно, спасибо, интересный способ